# Visualisation of Core Data entities and relationships

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically make a chart of all the Core Data entities and relationships between the entities? A chart, like a goal tree for example.
And I don't mean the metamodel (like the Datamodel of Xcode).. but an actual model of the elements present the database

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the "editor style" in XCode (lower right) to "Table, Graph" ? (with your .xdatamodel selected)